# Why is the plus sign (+) before a string value accepted in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Ok, this is perhaps a quirkiness of the Oracle parser.

The following query works. Note the + before 'Y' on the last line.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 'Y' AS field FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'X' AS field FROM DUAL) t
 WHERE t.field = +'Y'
```

Why is the Oracle parser accepting this? For a second I thought it was because of the old outer join syntax but in that syntax the + is surrounded with parentheses.

This works as well:

```
select +'Y1' from dual;
```

and this:

```
select 'A' || + 'Y1' from dual;
```

This works (oracle converts the string to a number):

```
select -'1' from DUAL;
```

but not this ([Error] Execution (223: 9): ORA-01722: invalid number
):

```
select -'A' from DUAL;
```

I wonder why the + can be used before a varchar2 value. The [Arithmetic Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/operators002.htm#SQLRF51156) section doesn't mention specific rules that would apply to string values.

Comment: Funny. Parser just parses so it doesn't consider the data types and + <expression> is valid expression. It could be also optimization that is applied because unary + doesn't modify the expression and it can be optimized away. Just checked `SELECT - - 1 FROM DUAL` and this is gramatically incorrect although matematically is correct.

Comment: @Husqvik, That's funny. The Arithmetic Operators page OP links has a warning against `--` for double negation, because that starts a comment. Says to separate with a space or paren.

Comment: @Husqvik: When I said parser I really meant the whole stack, parser, compiler, optimizer etc. Yes +<expression> is valid. I would have thought select - -1 from dual works. - - 1 is valid in c#, javascript and java but not in scala.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: The query included a space between the two minuses.

Comment: @costa, that's the funny part. Oracle implies it will work, but it doesn't.

Comment: BTW, SQL Server 2008 R2 displays similar behavior with the unary `+`, but it is documented as only working on numeric types.

Comment: Works in SQL Server and Sqlite too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unary `+` operator is defined as *identity* See the [Table 4-1 "SQL Operator Precedence"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators001.htm#BCFJDBDD) in [About SQL Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators001.htm).

Also:

```
select + date '2015-01-01' from dual;
```

> January, 01 2015 00:00:00

---

Edited to add.

"Identity" being to return its argument. For another example from a different language see Clojure's [`identity`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/identity) function. Wikipedia has a page for ["identity function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function).

Comment: What does identity mean in this context?